# i3 - bigger borders on floating windows

Tags: linux, i3

I frequently switch my windows to/from floating when using `i3`, either by `float toggle` or when I'm using `scratchpad`.

However, when I do this I want the borders of the windows to become larger - mainly since I want to be able to easily click the border to resize the window. I also want the border to fall back to the default size when they return to tiling mode.

So far, I have only found a way to define the border size for windows that automatically float, and if I toggle them the borders do not go back to the default size.

Is there any way to do this in `i3`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `for_window` with `tiling_from` and `floating_from` criteria in order to create separate rules for floating and tiling windows (see [for_window](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#for_window) and [command criteria](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#command_criteria) for more details). Usually I don't use this configuration, but it seems like putting this in the i3 config file works fine:

```
for_window [tiling_from="user"] border pixel 1
for_window [tiling_from="auto"] border pixel 1
for_window [floating_from="user"] border pixel 5
```

By doing so you'll get 1px border for tiling windows and 5px border for windows you make floating.

Note, that for some reason, using `for_window [tiling]` is not working in this case.